# How do I make ta.barssince count correctly in pine script? Sometimes it doesn't count the most recent condition

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

```
g1 = ta.barssince(close <= adj_bollinger1 or close <= adj_bolliner2)

g2 = ta.barssince(close >= adj_bollinger1 or close >= adj_bolliner2)



if close > adj_bollinger1 and close > adj_bolliner2
    closeUPDWBollinger := green
    barsSinceCloseHupdwBollinger := g1
else if close < adj_bollinger1 and close < adj_bolliner2
    closeUPDWBollinger := red
    barsSinceCloseHupdwBollinger := g2
else 
    closeUPDWBollinger := color.gray
    barsSinceCloseHupdwBollinger := -0
```

Essentially, I want to know the number of bars since close is outside upper/lower Bollinger. 
Problem arises when the bar count continues despite close going back inside and closing AND then the next bar going back out again to make the condition true. 
I want it to reset to zero and continue on from that dip. Sometimes it only starts counting a few bars AFTER the condition had been true. 
Thank you.

Comment: Please, complet your question : what is adj_bollinger1 and adj_bolloner2 ?

Comment: StdDev 1 and StdDev 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code did have syntax error.
Try this one :

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay=true, max_labels_count = 500)
[adj_bollinger1, middle, adj_bollinger2] = ta.bb(close,20,2)
g1 = ta.barssince(close <= adj_bollinger1 or close <= adj_bollinger2)
g2 = ta.barssince(close >= adj_bollinger1 or close >= adj_bollinger2)

closeUPDWBollinger = color.white
barsSinceCloseHupdwBollinger = 0

if close > adj_bollinger1 and close > adj_bollinger2
    closeUPDWBollinger := color.green
    barsSinceCloseHupdwBollinger := g1
else if close < adj_bollinger1 and close < adj_bollinger2
    closeUPDWBollinger := color.red
    barsSinceCloseHupdwBollinger := g2
else 
    closeUPDWBollinger := color.gray
    barsSinceCloseHupdwBollinger := 0
 
plot(adj_bollinger1, color=color.green)
plot(adj_bollinger2, color=color.red)
label.new(bar_index,close,str.tostring(barsSinceCloseHupdwBollinger), 
color=closeUPDWBollinger, yloc=closeUPDWBollinger==color.green?yloc.abovebar:yloc.belowbar)
```

To get this : 
[image]